# Why does Qrow live with Tai?

Tags: rwby

If Qrow was a teacher at Signal Academy and if he and Tai don't like each other (which I'm sure they don't) why does Qrow not get his own place? If you watch the right episodes you can see Qrow is at Tai's almost all the time except when he is gone on a mission also there is a joke in RWBY Chibi about Qrow and Tai being an old married couple though this more about the way they both take care of the girls more than anything else (they're not really married to each other)  so why does he stick around?!

Answer (score 2):

Because they're friends. Also Qrow probably don't have enough money to get his own place and Raven left Tai Summer dead, he has to have someone to help him watch the kids. (And Qrow is his former team mate as proved [here](http://rwby.wikia.com/wiki/STRQ), plus it was said in the show that Tai, Raven, Qrow, and Summer were all on the same team.)

Comment: No need to be rude.

Comment: Please use punctuation. As it stands, this is one long, nonsensical sentence. Also please back up your claims with sources and references to the show, rather than just making unsubstantiated claims.